# How to multithread an SNMP python request loop using input file for targets

Tags: python, multithreading, pysnmp, tqdm

I have a working iteration of an Python for loop using SNMP to pull values. I have gotten TQDM to work to give progress (for the most part aside from some weird characters). I am attempting to multithread, but am unable to get it working. This basic test is only using 51 lines; but in production it will be closer to 4000.

To fix the TQDM characters, I have tried it with progressbar, progressbar2, and tqdm...but overall this is just aesthetics. Multithreading attempts take the first line, but then stops.

```
~# cat text.py 
from tqdm import tqdm
import csv

linecounter = sum(1 for line in open('palo_list','r'))
pbar = tqdm(total=linecounter)
myfile = open("palo_list", "r")
for line in myfile:
    SNMP_HOST = line

    def snmpget(oid):
        from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen

        global pbar
        global SNMP_HOST
        SNMP_PORT = 161
        SNMP_COMMUNITY = 'public_fake'

        cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()

        errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = cmdGen.getCmd(
          cmdgen.CommunityData(SNMP_COMMUNITY),
          cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget((SNMP_HOST, SNMP_PORT)),
           oid
        )

        # Check for errors and print out results
        if errorIndication:
            print(errorIndication)
        else:
         if errorStatus:
            print('%s at %s' % (
                errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1] or '?'
            )
                  )
         else:
            for name, val in varBinds:
                return val

    HOSTNAME = snmpget('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0')
    MODEL = snmpget('1.3.6.1.4.1.25461.2.1.2.2.1.0')
    SERIAL = snmpget('1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.11.1')
    PANOS = snmpget('1.3.6.1.4.1.25461.2.1.2.1.1.0')

    csvRow = [HOSTNAME, MODEL, SERIAL, PANOS]
    csvfile = "palo2.csv"
    with open(csvfile, "a") as fp:
        wr = csv.writer(fp, dialect='excel')
        wr.writerow(csvRow)
    pbar.update(1)
myfile.close()
```

Expected results are a multithreaded loop with "pretty" progress bar...what I get without threading is:

```
~# python text.py 
100%|‚ñà‚ñà‚ñà‚ñà‚ñà‚ñà‚ñà‚ñà‚ñà‚ñà| 51/51 [01:14<00:00,  1.47s/it]
```

With threading:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import csv
import threading
import Queue

NUM_THREADS = 4
semaphore = threading.Semaphore(NUM_THREADS)
threads = NUM_THREADS
running_threads = []
lock = threading.Lock()
q = Queue.Queue()

lock.acquire()
    linecounter = sum(1 for line in open('palo_list','r'))
    bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(maxval=int(linecounter)).start()
    devices = 0
    myfile = open("palo_list", "r")
    for line in myfile:
        SNMP_HOST = line

        def snmpget(oid):
            from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen

            global devices
            global SNMP_HOST
            SNMP_PORT = 161
            SNMP_COMMUNITY = 'public_fake'

            cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()

            errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = cmdGen.getCmd(
              cmdgen.CommunityData(SNMP_COMMUNITY),
              cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget((SNMP_HOST, SNMP_PORT)),
               oid
            )

            # Check for errors and print out results
            if errorIndication:
                print(errorIndication)
            else:
             if errorStatus:
                print('%s at %s' % (
                    errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                    errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1] or '?'
                )
                      )
             else:
                for name, val in varBinds:
                    return val

        HOSTNAME = snmpget('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0')
        MODEL = snmpget('1.3.6.1.4.1.25461.2.1.2.2.1.0')
        SERIAL = snmpget('1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.11.1')
        PANOS = snmpget('1.3.6.1.4.1.25461.2.1.2.1.1.0')

        print(HOSTNAME)

        csvRow = [HOSTNAME, MODEL, SERIAL, PANOS]
        csvfile = "palo.csv"
        with open(csvfile, "a") as fp:
            wr = csv.writer(fp, dialect='excel')
            wr.writerow(csvRow)
        bar.update(devices+1)
    myfile.close()
lock.release()

~# python text.py 
  0%|          | 0/51 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
~#
```

Comment: What have you tried when attempting to make a multithreaded version?

Comment: Added threading code above